# Invalid block type: Magento\CMS\Block\Block (magento 2)

Tags: magento2, php, cms

I have created custom CMS block with ID:headerlink

I am calling it in header/logo.phtml

with this code

```
<?php echo $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\CMS\Block\Block')->blockId('headerlink')->toHtml();?>
```

but I am getting this error, as cms block class not found

```
2 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Invalid block type: Magento\CMS\Block\Block
Exception #1 (ReflectionException): Class Magento\CMS\Block\Block does not exist
```

Answer (score 4):

It should be

```
<?php echo $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')->setBlockId('headerlink')->toHtml();?>
```

Comment: +1 from me. But still 1 exception is there as 1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Invalid method Magento\Cms\Block\Block::blockId

Comment: Right, not ->blockId() but ->setBlockId()

Comment: I will accept it as answer